# How we can get BootAnimation.zip Location in android with adb.exe?

Tags: android, boot-animation

In different android phones location of "bootanimation.zip" are not the same.  In this case we want to find true location of "bootanimation.zip" with adb.exe. Is it possible to help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `system/media` or `system/customize/resource` or `data/local`. If you find a `bootanimation.zip` file in one of those, that is probably the location it is on your phone.

Comment: I found that the boot animation video is a file called 'bootvideo' under /vendor/etc/ in my Android 9 device. It's an .mp4 file without extension.